# Change color of span tag depending on value

Tags: javascript, html, jinja2

I want to change the color of the `message` variable in the following HTML:

```
<span id="mess" style="visibility:visible;">
                <text id="tex">{{ message }}</text>
</span
```

I am using Jinja2 together with Flask - Python to pass a value to the `{{ message }}`
variable. Here is how I tried to do it:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

            if (document.getElementById('tex').value == 'Message sent !')
            {
                document.getElementById('tex').setAttribute("style", "color:green;");
            }
            else
            {
                document.getElementById('tex').setAttribute("style", "color:red;");
            }
});
```

The result of the `document.getElementById('tex').value` is always `undefined` and the color of the text of the `message` variable is always red.

Is there a way with which I can accomplish that ? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why do you want to use `Vanilla JS` if you are also using `jQuery`

Comment: It is a project I am doing for practice purposes and I wanted to practice on some Javascript as well. That's the only reason why.

Comment: `<text>` isn't a standard tag, and only form fields have values. It would be much cleaner to set a class with Flask and style it with CSS instead of changing the color with JavaScript.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lets use contains selector.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  if ($('#tex:contains("Message sent !")').length) {
    $('#tex').css('color', 'green');
  } else {
    $('#tex').css('color', 'red');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="mess" style="visibility:visible;">
  <text id="tex">Message sent !</span>
</span>
```