# How to change the color of a span tag dynamically?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to build a slider. The Slider has a range of between 0 and 30 jumping 10 steps each time, so: 0, 10, 20, 30. At each of these 4 levels I've placed an empty circle. Currently, whenever I click on a level on the slider, the relevant part of the slider is painted in the expected colour. For example, a click on level 10, means the slider is painted in the given colour from 0-10. What I'm now trying to do is, getting the circles within a clicked level to have the same colour too, for instance I click  level 10, and get circles placed at 0 and 10  to have the same colour too. I have the following code, that I've so far worked on:

```js
function sliderVal(range){

    var nodes=document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
    for (let i=0;i<nodes.length;i++){
        nodes[i].style.backgroundColor = "#DADDe3";                      
    }
    for (let i=0;i<range;i++){
        console.log(nodes[i].id)
        nodes[i].style.backgroundColor = "#84b7e3";         
    }

}
```

```css
input[type=range] {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 3.9px 0;
}

input[type="range"]:focus {
  outline: none;  
  }
 input[type="range"]{
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-apperance: none;
    border-radius: 11px;
    height: 11px;
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(
        linear,
        left top,
        right top,
        color-stop(0.15, #84b7e3),
        color-stop(0.15, #DADDe3)
    );
}


input[type='range']::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    -webkit-appearance: none !important;
    /*background-color: #E9E9E9;*/
    /*border: 1px solid #CECECE;**/

  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0.5px #000000, 0px 0.6px 1px #0d0d0d;
  border: 0px solid #000000;
  width: 20.035px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  background: #3072ac;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-top: 0px;  
}
input[type=range]::-moz-range-track {
  width: 100%;
  height: 11px;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 0.2px 0.2px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), 0px 0px 0.2px rgba(13, 13, 13, 0);
  background: #DADDe3;
  border-radius: 1.3px;
  border: 0px solid #010101;
}
input[type="range"]::-moz-range-progress {
  height: 11px;
  background-color: #84b7e3; 
}
input[type=range]::-moz-range-thumb {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0.5px #000000, 0px 0px 0px #0d0d0d;
  border: 0px solid #000000;
  height: 18px;
  width: 18px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  background: #3072ac;
  cursor: pointer;
}

input[type=range]::-ms-track {
  width: 100%;
  height: 11px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: transparent;
  border-color: transparent;
  color: transparent;
}
input[type=range]::-ms-fill-lower {
  background: #6fabde;
  border: 0px solid #010101;
  border-radius: 2.6px;
  box-shadow: 0.2px 0.2px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), 0px 0px 0.2px rgba(13, 13, 13, 0);
}
input[type=range]::-ms-fill-upper {
  background: #84b7e3;
  border: 0px solid #010101;
  border-radius: 2.6px;
  box-shadow: 0.2px 0.2px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), 0px 0px 0.2px rgba(13, 13, 13, 0);
}
input[type=range]::-ms-thumb {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0.5px #000000, 0px 0px 0px #0d0d0d;
  border: 0px solid #000000;
  height: 18px;
  width: 18px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  background: #3072ac;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 11px;
}
input[type=range]:focus::-ms-fill-lower {
  background: #84b7e3;
}
input[type=range]:focus::-ms-fill-upper {
  background: #99c3e8;
}

.dot {
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  background-color: #DADDe3;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
}

#slider1{
    position:absolute;
    top: 77%;
    left: 0%;
}

#slider2{
    position:absolute;
    top: 77%;
    left: 10%;
}

#slider3{
    position:absolute;
    top: 77%;
    left: 20%;
}
#slider3{
    position:absolute;
    top: 77%;
    left: 30%;
}
```

```html
<div  class="slidecontainer" style="position: relative">
<input style="position: absolute" type="range" min="0" max="30" value="0" step="10" class="slider" id="myRange" onClick="sliderVal('value/10')">

<span class="dot" id="slider1" ></span>
<span class="dot" id="slider2" ></span>
<span class="dot" id="slider3"></span>
<span class="dot" id="slider4" ></span>
</div>
```

Unfortunately my clicklistener in the js file is not doing its job and the circles don't change their colour. As you can see, to create circles I used an empty span tag. I am completely new to HTML/Javascript and have the feeling I could/should have used something other than the span tag for what I want. Is there a way to make these span tags change their background color by modifying the above code? or should I use something else (maybe a circle icon or something) for that purpose? I know this isn't an original question. But answers to similar questions I found at [Change color of span tag depending on value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47663957/change-color-of-span-tag-depending-on-value) and also w3schools at https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_css.asp didn't really help so far. Any suggestions?

Comment: try `onChange="sliderVal('value/10')"` instead of `onClick`

Comment: that didnt help really..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you need to change the onClick to `onchange` notice all lowercase which is the html property name for the event handler and then pass the function with the value as `this.value` so you'll end up with:

```
<div  class="slidecontainer" style="position: relative">
    <input style="position: absolute" type="range" min="0" max="30" value="0" step="10" class="slider" id="myRange" onchange="sliderVal(this.value/10)">

    <span class="dot" id="slider1" ></span>
    <span class="dot" id="slider2" ></span>
    <span class="dot" id="slider3"></span>
    <span class="dot" id="slider4" ></span>
</div>
```

and js

```
function sliderVal(range){
    var nodes=document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
    for (let i=0;i<nodes.length;i++){
        nodes[i].style.backgroundColor = "#DADDe3";                      
    }
    for (let i=0;i<range;i++){
        console.log(nodes[i].id)
        nodes[i].style.backgroundColor = "#84b7e3";         
    }

}
```

**[Working DEMO](https://codepen.io/Amin52J/pen/JjjREYE)**

Comment: Amin thank you so much! Devil is in the detail... lowercasing it solved my problem..

Comment: true that, glad I could help

Answer (score 0):

Here is really working dynamic example with change on slide:

```js
function sliderVal(range){

    var nodes=document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
    for (let i=0;i<nodes.length;i++){
        nodes[i].style.backgroundColor = "#DADDe3";                      
    }
    for (let i=0;i<range;i++){
        console.log(nodes[i].id)
        nodes[i].style.backgroundColor = "#84b7e3";         
    }

}
```

```css
input[type=range] {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 3.9px 0;
}

input[type="range"]:focus {
  outline: none;  
  }
 input[type="range"]{
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-apperance: none;
    border-radius: 11px;
    height: 11px;
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(
        linear,
        left top,
        right top,
        color-stop(0.15, #84b7e3),
        color-stop(0.15, #DADDe3)
    );
}


input[type='range']::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    -webkit-appearance: none !important;
    /*background-color: #E9E9E9;*/
    /*border: 1px solid #CECECE;**/

  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0.5px #000000, 0px 0.6px 1px #0d0d0d;
  border: 0px solid #000000;
  width: 20.035px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  background: #3072ac;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-top: 0px;  
}
input[type=range]::-moz-range-track {
  width: 100%;
  height: 11px;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 0.2px 0.2px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), 0px 0px 0.2px rgba(13, 13, 13, 0);
  background: #DADDe3;
  border-radius: 1.3px;
  border: 0px solid #010101;
}
input[type="range"]::-moz-range-progress {
  height: 11px;
  background-color: #84b7e3; 
}
input[type=range]::-moz-range-thumb {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0.5px #000000, 0px 0px 0px #0d0d0d;
  border: 0px solid #000000;
  height: 18px;
  width: 18px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  background: #3072ac;
  cursor: pointer;
}

input[type=range]::-ms-track {
  width: 100%;
  height: 11px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: transparent;
  border-color: transparent;
  color: transparent;
}
input[type=range]::-ms-fill-lower {
  background: #6fabde;
  border: 0px solid #010101;
  border-radius: 2.6px;
  box-shadow: 0.2px 0.2px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), 0px 0px 0.2px rgba(13, 13, 13, 0);
}
input[type=range]::-ms-fill-upper {
  background: #84b7e3;
  border: 0px solid #010101;
  border-radius: 2.6px;
  box-shadow: 0.2px 0.2px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), 0px 0px 0.2px rgba(13, 13, 13, 0);
}
input[type=range]::-ms-thumb {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0.5px #000000, 0px 0px 0px #0d0d0d;
  border: 0px solid #000000;
  height: 18px;
  width: 18px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  background: #3072ac;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 11px;
}
input[type=range]:focus::-ms-fill-lower {
  background: #84b7e3;
}
input[type=range]:focus::-ms-fill-upper {
  background: #99c3e8;
}

.dot {
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  background-color: #DADDe3;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
}

#slider1{
    position:absolute;
    top: 77%;
    left: 0%;
}

#slider2{
    position:absolute;
    top: 77%;
    left: 10%;
}

#slider3{
    position:absolute;
    top: 77%;
    left: 20%;
}
#slider3{
    position:absolute;
    top: 77%;
    left: 30%;
}
```

```html
<div  class="slidecontainer" style="position: relative">
<input style="position: absolute" type="range" min="0" max="30" value="0" step="10" class="slider" id="myRange" oninput="sliderVal(Math.trunc(this.value/10))" onchange="sliderVal(Math.trunc(this.value/10))">

<span class="dot" id="slider1" ></span>
<span class="dot" id="slider2" ></span>
<span class="dot" id="slider3"></span>
<span class="dot" id="slider4" ></span>
</div>
```